# How can I get left-sided-sequence with InverseZTransform

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, integral-transforms

```
InverseZTransform[z^2/((4 - z)*(z - 1/4)), z, n, Assumptions -> {1/4 < Abs[z] < 4}]

(* -(1/15) 4^-n (-1 + 16^(1 + n)) *)
```

the result is not true.It only give me the right-sided-sequence.The range of |z| is between 1/4 and 4.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful